# Does $X, X^t$ have same operator norm.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, soft-question, operator-theory, matrix-decomposition

Let $X= [x_{i,j}]\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and its transpose is defined by
$$
X^t= [x_{j,i}].
$$

Then the linear operators $X, X^t: \mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ is defined by
$$
X\begin{bmatrix}
h_{1}\\
\vdots\\
h_{n}
\end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{1k}h_{k}\\
  \vdots\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{nk}h_{k}\\
\end{bmatrix}  \text{ for all }\begin{bmatrix}
h_{1}\\
\vdots\\
h_{n}
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^n,$$

and
$$ 
X^t\begin{bmatrix}
h_{1}\\
\vdots\\
h_{n}
\end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{ki}h_{k}\\
  \vdots\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{kn}h_{k}\\
\end{bmatrix} \text{ for all }\begin{bmatrix}
h_{1}\\
\vdots\\
h_{n}
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^n.
$$

Can yo say the operator norm of $X$  and $X^t$ are equal ( ie. $\Vert X\Vert = \Vert X^t\Vert$)?

I am curious to know when such equality happens? Thanks in advance for providing the suggestions.

Caution: We have not consider here $X^t$ as a conjugate transpose. In such case the result is very well known.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left\|X\right\| &= \max_{\left\|h\right\|=1} \left\|Xh\right\|\\
&= \max_{\left\|h\right\|=1} \left\|\overline X^T h\right\|\\
&= \max_{\left\|\overline h\right\|=1} \left\|\overline X^T \overline h\right\|\\
&= \max_{\left\|h\right\|=1} \left\|\overline {X^T h}\right\|\\
&= \max_{\left\|h\right\|=1} \left\|{X^T h}\right\| = \left\|X^T\right\|\\
\end{align}